# How to connect manage.py syncdb to google cloud sql

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gcloud

When i run ./manage.py syncdb throws error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name', (2)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible causes for this:

1. You forgot to whitelist (authorize) the IP from which you're connecting to the Cloud SQL instance, or
2. You are not using the proper syntax to name your instance. As the error says it's *'/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name'*. For example *'/cloudsql/aproject:myCloudSQLInstance'*.